# Adjective or Adverb in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> NJC Surveys recently determined that, despite advances in audio technology, it is still ...(predominant/predominantly)... through radio broadcasts that listeners are exposed to new music.

The answer in my textbook is predominantly.
Could you please explain?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, and thanks for your question. Have you learned the difference between an _adverb_ and an _adjective_ in English? Please **[edit]** your question to tell us what _you_ think is correct, and why. Before you ask another question, take the time to read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you understand how to write a great question!

Answer (score 2):

The word in question modifies *is*, because rather than being all the time (that would be "it is still through radio broadcasts"), it is *predominantly* which basically means mostly or most importantly, but not always.

Since the word you are modifying is a verb, you need to use an adverb. In this case, *predominantly*.